# Maximum User limit of People Picker Field

Tags: people-picker

i have many number of users... and assign same task for all those users..
So i want to know what is the maximum users limit of people picker field.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? Or work it out yourself?

Comment: Seems odd that there isn't a direct answer for this

Answer (score 2):

The maximun limit for:

- **SharePoint 2010** - 96
- **SharePoint 2013** - default 200

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms442451(v%3Doffice.14)

It can be changed to 750 using - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms448431%28v%3doffice.14%29

Review this for limitation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits

Comment: I am looking for the same limitation for SharePoint Online but couldn't find anything. Please share if you know the answer.