# Maximum number of users in MultiSelect User field for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

I am looking for an answer on how many users I can store for Multi Select user field.

Tried looking around but couldn't find the answer.

One of the below link someone answer the same question for 2010 and 2013 but not for SharePoint Online.

[Maximum User limit of People Picker Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58111/maximum-user-limit-of-people-picker-field)

Comment: I just ran a test with 357 users in a multi-select Person field. After resolving all the user objects, it saved fine. That's everyone in our directory so I can't test further, sry

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the official documentation for it, but I think it should be the same as SharePoint server, with a maximum value set to 750.

[image]

Comment: Wrote a script which adds users and was able to store more than 750 :) will try with higher number to see the limit.